# App crashes on launch of Activity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

App is crashing when activity is loaded but if I uncomment the Make Register text as link to website, the code works, but the exact same copy of the code just different link will crash the app, code below.

The activity is for a login page with links to register and to reset password

LogCat

```
08-04 21:34:07.006 11888-11888/net.twistedcircuits.greenroadsmalta 
D/LOGIN PAGE: ______login page loaded
08-04 21:34:07.006 11888-11888/net.twistedcircuits.greenroadsmalta D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    08-04 21:34:07.007 11888-11888/net.twistedcircuits.greenroadsmalta E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                         Process: net.twistedcircuits.greenroadsmalta, PID: 11888
                                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.twistedcircuits.greenroadsmalta/net.twistedcircuits.greenroadsmalta.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setMovementMethod(android.text.method.MovementMethod)' on a null object reference
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2924)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635)
                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
                                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setMovementMethod(android.text.method.MovementMethod)' on a null object reference
                                                                                             at net.twistedcircuits.greenroadsmalta.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:56)
                                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
                                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2877)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985) 
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635) 
                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692) 
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468) 
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Activity

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        //lock screen for always Portrait mode
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        Log.d("LOGIN PAGE","______login page loaded");

        loginEmail = (EditText) (findViewById(R.id.LoginEmail_editText));
        loginPassword = (EditText) (findViewById(R.id.LoginPassword_editText));


        //************************ Make Register text as link to website ************************//
/*
        registerLinkText = (TextView) (findViewById(R.id.registerLink_textView));
        registerLinkText.setClickable(true);
        registerLinkText.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

        register_text = "<a href='http://www.google.com'>No account yet? Create One</a>";
        registerLinkText.setText(fromHtml(register_text));
        registerLinkText.setLinkTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.loginTextColor));
*/
        //**********************************************************************************//

        //************************ Make Lost Password text as link to website ************************//
        lostPasswordLinkText = (TextView) (findViewById(R.id.lostPasswordLink_textView));
        lostPasswordLinkText.setClickable(true);
        registerLinkText.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

        password_text = "<a href='https://www.google.com.mt/search?q=dementia&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWyovunL7VAhXDzRQKHa2ND_0QBQgkKAA&biw=1152&bih=956'>Forgot your password?</a>";
        lostPasswordLinkText.setText(fromHtml(password_text));
        lostPasswordLinkText.setLinkTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.loginTextColor));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`registerLinkText` is null. It has not been bound to a view from xml layout.

```
registerLinkText = (TextView) (findViewById(R.id.registerLink_textView));
```

Uncomment this above line.

Comment: That part works if I uncomment the line above but the problem is the block of code below  //***** Make Lost Password text as link to website ******//

Comment: aaaaa shoot got it thanks :)